# Wordpress Elementor Custom Query to show posts equal to or after certain date

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am building a sports club website with match fixtures. Each fixture is made in a custom post type with ACF fields and I am using the custom acf field called match_date as a date for showing fixtures.

I am trying to show in an elementor loop grid widget a custom query to show the the next fixtures which i am able to do with the code below and it is working fine if the match date is not todays date...

But it is only showing future match fixtures and not fixtures with "todays" date, I have tried to change the 'compare' to '>=' but it is not working to show fixture date with the current/todays date.

```
add_action('elementor/query/next_fixtures', function($query){ 
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'match_date',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATETIME'
        ],
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
});
```

Comment: If you want this to work based on dates, then why is your comparison value including a time portion?

Comment: Are the posts published? If they are scheduled to be published, you might need to add `$query->set( 'post_status', [ 'future', 'publish' ] );` - or you could set post_status to 'any'. Try that.